# jdbc/jdbcio apache beam performance comparision for 100 million records

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

We are about to opt apache beam for our dataflow programming. Considering all complex DML operations involved, what is the performance stats for 100 million records when i use jdbc/jdbcio. which one is faster and easy, either jdbc or jdbcio?

Comment: I think it is hard to have a number for general case. You might have to design a small benchmark to test it. The performance bottleneck might be the sources/sinks you read/write, not from Beam.

Comment: I agree it depends on the source and sink rather than Apache Beam but I would like to know if i proceed with plain old java jdbc for db operations rather than implementing complex jdbcio inside apache beam , what are the pros and cons if i choose either of them.

Comment: Beam has a JdbcIO already: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java. Is it satisfied your need?

Comment: I already went through the jdbcio documentation,its uses and code also. Actually the problem statement i had is, all the db stuff was developed with beam sdk 2.2.0 and there is no jdbcio available at that time. To re-write the existing jdbc code with jdbcio is huge effort for us, so i am searching for optimization with existing jdbc.